# Erroneous compiler warning when using 'objc_requires_super'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, llvm

So I recently [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16094396/442718) about a handy LLVM feature that produces compiler warnings whenever you forget to call super. When I tried using it in combination with a method defined in a protocol though, I received erroneous compiler warnings.

Here's what I want to achieve:

I'm trying to re-use code for creating a desired behavior in all my view controllers that use a scroll view, so I implemented an abstract view controller base class for use throughout the project:

```
@interface GCOViewController : UIViewController

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView __attribute__((objc_requires_super));

@end

@implementation GCOViewController

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
   // Do something (doesn't matter what exactly)
}

@end
```

In my concrete view controller subclasses I'm calling the code like this:

```
@interface GCOConcreteViewController : GCOViewController
@end

@implementation GCOConcreteViewController

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
   [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

   // Do some additional things in the concrete subclass
}

@end
```

While the functionality itself works like it's supposed to the compiler still shows me the warning

```
Method possibly missing a [super scrollViewDidScroll:] call
```

Any thought's on this behavior? Looks like a bug, doesn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that was a copy & paste mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my original question accordingly.

Comment: I didn't get this. Why do you re-define the scrollview's deletgate method directly.  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and your example compiles just fine.  Check through every class that descends from this abstract base class.  They all have to call through to super in their override.

Comment: What's the output of `clang -v`?

Comment: @CodaFi You're right, when adding this code to an empty project it compiles without any warnings. Curiously enough, I'm using `objc_requires_super`  on other methods (e. g. `-viewDidLoad`) without any problems in the same project that gives me undesired warnings for `-scrollViewDidScroll:`. Will investigate further.

Comment: @一二三 Couldn't find any useful additional information when running clang with verbose output. That's the error message when using `clang -v`: `/path/to/project/GCOConcreteViewController.m:861:1: warning: method possibly missing a [super scrollViewDidScroll:] call [-Wobjc-missing-super-calls]`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `clang --version`

Comment: @一二三 Ah alright, good idea, that results in `Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)` on my machine. I'm running Xcode 4.6.2 on OS X 10.8.3. The deployment target is iOS 6.0.